# Access token in Swagger

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to secure my urls with a simple access token param. 
e.g. `https://localhost:4200/api/me/name?accessToken={someString}`

Is there any way that I could add this `accessToken` param similar to bearer token in swagger that it would be sent with each request in swagger?

Also, how can I make swagger accessible only with this access token? e.g. `https://localhost:4200/swagger?accessToken={someString}`

[image: Similar to bearer token]

I want that here instead of bearer token would be access token.

I am using asp .net core 2.2-3.1.

Comment: Do you mean how to define such access token in OpenAPI YAML/JSON, or using source code annotations? If the latter, do you use Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net or something else, and what version?

Comment: I want to configure it by source code. I am using Swashbuckle latest version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Swagger/Swashbuckle to append an API key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56535077/113116)

Comment: I think yes. Thanks!